# How to use Cages (or Zookeeper) to simulate transactions in cassandra - example codes needed

Tags: cassandra, apache-zookeeper, nosql

Please I have a use case where I need to simulate ACID-like transaction in cassandra and I came across this library called cages for locking writes and reads operation in cassandra, I actually got stuck at the point where they specified a "lockpath". I have read the article at this 
[link](https://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/locking-and-transactions-over-cassandra-using-cages/) and it is not explicit enough for a Zookeeper-novice like me. i would really appreciate a Step by Step explanation or a simple example code, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into using lightweight transactions instead? Whats the usecase?

Comment: the use case goes thus:
1. Debit an account A with a certain amount (say $10)
2. Credit another account B with that amount $10
3. Log the operation on another table.

I need to wrap the whole operation up in a transaction so that I can rollback if anything goes wrong